# websocket tokio-tungstenite consume messages from queue

Tags: rust, websocket, rust-tokio

I am developing a websocket server which should:

1. forward incoming websocket messages to a queue (done!).
2. send via websocket incoming messages from another queue (my question).

Background tasks will read from the queues to perform further processing of messages, I have simplified my app in order to ask the question.

I haven't been able to successfully pass the reciever to the websocket connection. First I tried using `tokio::sync::mpsc` but I realized that while you can pass the sender to multiple tasks, you cannot do the same with the reciever. I then thought that using a `tokio::sync::broadcast` channel would work but I have not been able to successfully compile the code.

I will use the `tokio::select!` macro in order to handle incoming / outgoing messages.

How should I modify the `accept_connection` function to access the reciever?

Here is the working code before implementing the last feature.

```
use std::{env, io::Error};

use futures_util::StreamExt;
use tokio::net::{TcpListener, TcpStream};
use tokio::sync::broadcast;

use tokio::sync::mpsc;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    let addr = env::args().nth(1).unwrap_or_else(|| "127.0.0.1:8080".to_string());

    // Create the event loop and TCP listener we'll accept connections on.
    let try_socket = TcpListener::bind(&addr).await;
    let listener = try_socket.expect("Failed to bind");

    // setup channel
    let (tx_from_ws, mut rx_from_ws) = mpsc::channel::<String>(32);

    let (tx_to_ws, mut rx_to_ws) = broadcast::channel::<String>(32);

    // print all messages received from websocket
    tokio::spawn(async move {
        while let Some(msg) = rx_from_ws.recv().await {
            println!("From websocket: {}", msg);
        }
    });

    // periodically send a message to all websocket connections
    tokio::spawn(async move {
        let mut interval = tokio::time::interval(tokio::time::Duration::from_secs(5));
        loop {
            interval.tick().await;
            tx_to_ws.send("Periodic message".to_string()).expect("Error while sending message to channel");
        }
    });

    while let Ok((stream, _)) = listener.accept().await {
        tokio::spawn(accept_connection(stream, tx_from_ws.clone()));
    }

    Ok(())
}

async fn accept_connection(stream: TcpStream, tx: mpsc::Sender<String>) {
    let addr = stream.peer_addr().expect("connected streams should have a peer address");

    let ws_stream = tokio_tungstenite::accept_async(stream)
        .await
        .expect("Error during the websocket handshake occurred");

    let (write, mut read) = ws_stream.split();

    loop {
        tokio::select! {
            Some(msg) = read.next() => {
                let msg = msg.expect("Error while reading from websocket");
                let msg = msg.to_text().expect("Error while converting message to text");
                tx.send(msg.to_string()).await.expect("Error while sending message to channel");
            }
            // handle incoming messages to the channel
        }
    }
}
```

My Cargo.toml file:

```
[package]
name = "rust-websocket-test"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
tokio = { version = "1.27.0", features = ["full"] }
tokio-tungstenite = "*"
futures-util = "0.3.17"
futures-channel = "0.3.17"
```

Here is the code after one attempt to implement the reciever:

```
use std::{env, io::Error};

use futures_util::StreamExt;
use tokio::net::{TcpListener, TcpStream};
use tokio::sync::broadcast;

use tokio::sync::mpsc;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    let addr = env::args().nth(1).unwrap_or_else(|| "127.0.0.1:8080".to_string());

    // Create the event loop and TCP listener we'll accept connections on.
    let try_socket = TcpListener::bind(&addr).await;
    let listener = try_socket.expect("Failed to bind");

    // setup channel
    let (tx_from_ws, mut rx_from_ws) = mpsc::channel::<String>(32);

    let (tx_to_ws, mut rx_to_ws) = broadcast::channel::<String>(32);
    // mutex over rx_to_ws

    // print all messages received from websocket
    tokio::spawn(async move {
        while let Some(msg) = rx_from_ws.recv().await {
            println!("From websocket: {}", msg);
        }
    });

    // periodically send a message to all websocket connections
    tokio::spawn(async move {
        let mut interval = tokio::time::interval(tokio::time::Duration::from_secs(5));
        loop {
            interval.tick().await;
            tx_to_ws.send("Periodic message".to_string()).expect("Error while sending message to channel");
        }
    });

    while let Ok((stream, _)) = listener.accept().await {
        tokio::spawn(accept_connection(stream, tx_from_ws.clone(), rx_to_ws.clone()));
    }

    Ok(())
}

async fn accept_connection(stream: TcpStream, tx: mpsc::Sender<String>, rx: broadcast::Receiver<String>) {
    let addr = stream.peer_addr().expect("connected streams should have a peer address");

    let ws_stream = tokio_tungstenite::accept_async(stream)
        .await
        .expect("Error during the websocket handshake occurred");

    let (write, mut read) = ws_stream.split();

    loop {
        tokio::select! {
            Some(msg) = read.next() => {
                let msg = msg.expect("Error while reading from websocket");
                let msg = msg.to_text().expect("Error while converting message to text");
                tx.send(msg.to_string()).await.expect("Error while sending message to channel");
            }
            // handle incoming messages to the channel
            Some(msg) = rx.recv() => {
                let msg = tokio_tungstenite::tungstenite::Message::text(msg);
                tokio::spawn(async move {
                    if let Err(e) = write.send(msg).await {
                        eprintln!("Error while sending message to websocket: {}", e);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? I.e. what is the full error message by `cargo build`? Your "[mre]" seems to work on my end.

Comment: Yes, my example works because I did not include the receiver in the code (because it does not compile). I tried many ways of passing it to the `accept_connection` and none worked so I just included the code just before this step. I will also include the code with a compiltion error.